# Calculate average with user inputs and different methods

Tags: java, methods, arguments, average, static-methods

So, my homework is to form a program that prompts the user for five to ten numbers all on one line, separated by spaces, calculates the average of those numbers, and displays the numbers and their average to the user.

The first method should take no arguments and return a String of numbers separated by spaces.

The second method should take a String as its only argument and return a double (the average).

The third method should take a String and a double as arguments but have no return value.

---

My issue is I have no clue how to calculate the average in a different method along with printing my results. I've just learned methods so I'm still trying to figure them out.

This is what I have so far and I know I have errors:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CalculateAvg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userinput = getuserinput();
    }


    public static String getuserinput() {
        // Read inputs and change string to double
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userinput;

        System.out.println("Please enter 5 to 10 numbers seperated by spaces: ");
        userinput = in.nextLine();
        double numbs = Double.parseDouble(userinput);
        return userinput;
    }
    // Problem is here. 
    public static double mySum(String sum, String userinput) {
        double avg = 0;
        double count = 0;

        double value = Double.parseDouble(sum);
        sum = sum + userinput;
        count++;
        avg = sum / count;

        return avg;
    }
}
```

Comment: `"... I have errors."` -- What errors? Please try to ask a more complete question.

Comment: the avg = sum / count; is giving me an error.

Answer (score 2):

As this is homework I'm not going to give you the code but rather point you in the right direction.

First, and foremost, follow the instructions. The first method should just get user input; nothing else. So, don't do anything else there. You won't be able to use it once the method returns anyway.

The second method should have only a single argument; don't use two then. Send the user input into that method and get the average. To get the average you need the sum and the count of numbers from the input. But you have a `String`. So, you need to split that string into the individual numbers and parse them into a numeric type, sum them, and then divide by the count you obtained after splitting the input.

I assume the third method will take the user input and the calculated double and display them in a clean manner.

Each of these tasks should be separate methods so it would resemble something like this:

```
input = getInput()
average = getAverage(input)
displayResults(input, average)
```

Comment: `String[] result = userinput.split(" ");
double numbs = Double.parseDouble(userinput);`

I've added string split and the parse for double but i get an error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5 4"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
 at calculateavg.CalculateAvg.getAverage(CalculateAvg.java:39)
 at calculateavg.CalculateAvg.main(CalculateAvg.java:19)

Comment: @Olive, think about what the error means and what userinput is. The input is still the space separated numbers. The result array is the individual numbers that need to be parsed to doubles and added together. So, you could add a loop and go over each in that array and add the parsed value to a sum variable initialized to 0. Then you have the sum and the size of the result array is the number of numbers entered.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hoping for an exact code then I am not going to give you that.

To take 5 to 10 arguments I think you can create an array make a for loop ( `in.nextInt()` will get the input ) and create a break statement inside the loop in a if statement.

If statement will check where to stop ( put some number that won't be in array and mark as end of arguments ).

This can be used when you are getting them as int.

If you want to read whole line as one then save the line string in str ( or something).

```
String[] nums = str.split(" ");
```

This statement will make all numbers stored in arrays of String.

To get the numbers use a for loop and `Double.parseDouble(nums[i])`.

Now if you are panicked to do this stuff in different methods then just use Global variables.

I think this much help might get your work done.

Comment: I would remove the alternative methods on how to achieve it from your answer; they have the requirements and they don't include taking individual numbers as `int`s from the user in a loop with a terminating value or using global variables.

Comment: So simply use in.next() to read whole line as input and try out the rest as told. In the beginning programming scares but don't be. We are here to help.

Comment: I'm not the OP. I was just kindly making a suggestion since they presumably won't be able to use the suggestions since they go against the homework requirements.